# Imperfect custom fold in vim-latex

Tags: vim-latex

I included the following custom fold in .vimrc

```
let g:Tex_FoldedEnvironments = ',frame,block,algorithm'
```

I have perfect folding of `frame` and `block`, but not for `algorithm`. It folds all the lines of `algorithm` except the last line `\end{algorithm}`.

The following open code:
[image]

looks like this:
[image]

How can I correct this?

FYI, my full .vimrc is the following:

```
execute pathogen#infect()

" from vim-latex installation manual
filetype plugin on
set shellslash
filetype indent on
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
let g:Tex_AdvancedMath = 1  " provides <Alt> mappings, overrides ASCII char insertion
" set winaltkeys=no " if there conflicts with menubar shortcuts

"compilation rules
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat='pdf'
" let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'pdflatex -interaction=batchmode $*'
let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode $*'

" Folding keyworkds
let g:Tex_FoldedEnvironments = ',frame,block,algorithm'

" mapping compile to w and W
map :ww :w<cr><leader>ll<cr><leader>lv
map :WW :ww

" mapping Caps H,J,K,L to navigation
map J j
" map K k
" map L l
" map H h

"line numbering
set number

"Spell check
set spell
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By design vim-latex with `let g:Tex_FoldedEnvironments='foo'` will fold any environment beginning `foo`, such that the environments `foo`, `foobar`, and `foobaz` will all be folded (see [8.2.2 Tex_FoldedEnvironments](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/customizing-what-to-fold.html#Tex_FoldedEnvironments)).

Unfortunately vim-latex appears not be checking that the beginning and ending environment match, and so is finding a `\begin{algorithm` and after that the first time it finds something beginning `\end{algorithm` is the `\end{algorithmic}` line.

The same advice given in [8.2.2 Tex_FoldedEnvironments](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/customizing-what-to-fold.html#Tex_FoldedEnvironments) to avoid `let g:Tex_FoldedEnvironments='foo'` folding the `foo` and `foobar` environments works here: `let g:Tex_FoldedEnvironments=',algorithm}'` will only fold `algorithm` and not `algorithmic`.

---

While it might also seem like it should work `let g:Tex_FoldedEnvironments=',algorithm,algorithmic'` folds `algorithmic` correctly but then matches `\begin{algorithm}` with `\end{algorithmic}` even though it's already folded `algorithmic`.